# State is not getting maintained after federation authentication for facebook

Tags: federated-authentication

This is my custom provider class:

```
public class Facebook : IdentityProvidersProcessor
{
    public Facebook(FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration federatedAuthenticationConfiguration,
                    ICookieManager cookieManager,
                    BaseSettings settings)
                    : base(federatedAuthenticationConfiguration, cookieManager, settings)
    {
    }

    protected override string IdentityProviderName => "Facebook";

    protected override void ProcessCore(IdentityProvidersArgs args)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, nameof(args));

        var identityProvider = this.GetIdentityProvider();
        var authenticationType = this.GetAuthenticationType();

        var options = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Caption = identityProvider.Caption,
            AuthenticationType = authenticationType,
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
            AppId = Settings.GetSetting("Feature.Accounts.Facebook.AppId"),
            AppSecret = Settings.GetSetting("Feature.Accounts.Facebook.AppSecret"),
            Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnAuthenticated = context =>
                {
                    context.Identity.ApplyClaimsTransformations(new TransformationContext(this.FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration, identityProvider));
                    AddClaim(context, "full_name", "name");
                    AddClaim(context, "email", "email");
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            },
            Scope =
            {
                "public_profile",
                "email"
            },
            Fields =
            {
                "name",
                "email",
            }
        };

        FacebookAuthenticationExtensions.UseFacebookAuthentication(args.App, options);
    }

    private void AddClaim(FacebookAuthenticatedContext context, string claimName, string propertyName)
    {
        var value = context.User[propertyName]?.ToString();
        if (propertyName == "picture")
        {
            value = context.User["picture"]?["data"]?["url"]?.ToString();
            if (value == null)
                return;
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("picture_url", value));
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("picture_mime", "image/jpg"));
            return;
        }

        if (value == null)
            return;
        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(claimName, value));
    }
}
```

So i am able to login by using facebook successfully but whenever i am changing the page the cache whatever i added at the time of facebook login getting removed.

Comment: What kind of cache are you talking about here? There is no cache in your examples.

Answer (score 0):

You need to login the FB user into Sitecore as a Virtual User. By doing that,you will be able to check from ***Sitecore.Context.User.IsAuthenticated*** on other pages ,if user is logged in/not, then show/hide relevant content. Below code block will create and login the virtual user. This can be used on the **OnAuthorizationCodeReceived()** of your Facebook pipeline

```
       User virtualUser = Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.BuildVirtualUser(userName, false);

        virtualUser.RuntimeSettings.Load();
        virtualUser.RuntimeSettings.AddedRoles.Clear();
        virtualUser.Roles.RemoveAll();

        // Optional: Add the user to an existing extranet role
        virtualUser.Roles.Add(Role.FromName("Facebook\\"));

        // set profile properties
        virtualUser.Profile.Email = userName;
        virtualUser.Profile.Name = displayName;
        virtualUser.Profile.FullName = displayName;
        virtualUser.Profile.Comment = "User Created from Facebook";
        foreach (var prop in properties)
        {
            // virtualUser.Profile.SetCustomProperty(prop.Key, prop.Value);
        }
        virtualUser.Profile.Save();
        virtualUser.RuntimeSettings.IsVirtual = true;

        virtualUser.RuntimeSettings.Save();
        user = virtualUser;
        _res = true;
        virtualUser.Profile.Reload();

        // Login the virtual user
        Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.LoginVirtualUser(virtualUser);
```

Comment: This might work but you should be very careful with this approach if you are under version 9.2. There is an issue when using LoginVirtualUser like this which can kill a site with a good amount of user. There is some info in the 9.2 release notes as well https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/92/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2092%20Initial%20Release/Release%20Notes